# Change dropdownlist to autocomplete in scheduler popup editor in Kendo MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler, kendo-dropdown, kendo-autocomplete

For example, I bind the resource as follows.

```
.Resources(resource =>
         {
            resource.Add(m => m.UserName)
                .Title("Staff")
                .Name("Staff")
                .DataTextField("Text")
                .DataValueField("Value")
                .DataSource(source => source
                    .Read(read => read.Action("GetStaffList", "Scheduler"))
                );
         })
```

When the editor popups, the staff input has type of dropdown list which contains all the Staff in database.

Question: How to change it to an autocomplete widget with server filtering by staff's name for example.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would jump into JavaScript by hooking up a event on edit to the grid, then you can do it there doing something like this

```
function onEdit(e) {
    //Autocompleter
    $("#Staff").kendoAutoComplete({
        dataSource: {
            serverFiltering: true,
            transport: {
                read: { url: "/Staff/GetListForAutocompleter" },
                parameterMap: function (data, action) {
                    var newParams = { filter: $("#Staff").val(), filter2: 'something' };
                    return newParams;
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```